# How do I overwrite a foreign key column in Entity Framework Core 6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 6. I have 3 tables, `order`, `orderitem` and `product` in SQL Server.

Primary key of `order` table is `id`, foreign keys in `orderitem` are `orderid` and `product_id`. Everything is set up correctly, however, the query that EF Core 6 generated is not using `product_id`, but keeps on using `productId` as the foreign key to map to the `product` table.  Where is the best place to overwrite that?

Here is the error part:

```
FROM [ShipEngineOrderItems] AS [s0]   
LEFT JOIN [Products] AS [p] ON [s0].[ProductId] = [p].[Id]
```

This is the full error message, the select statement above it uses the correct column name

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (90ms) [Parameters=[@__orderId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT [s].[id], [s].[order_date], [t].[PId], [t].[ProductName], [t].[Price], [t].[id], [t].[Id0]
> FROM [ShipEngineOrders] AS [s]
> LEFT JOIN (
> SELECT [s0].[product_id] AS [PId], [p].[WarehouseSku] AS [ProductName], [s0].[price] AS [Price], [s0].[id], [p].[Id] AS [Id0], [s0].[orderId]
> FROM [ShipEngineOrderItems] AS [s0]
> LEFT JOIN [Products] AS [p] ON [s0].[ProductId] = [p].[Id]
> ) AS [t] ON [s].[id] = [t].[orderId]
> WHERE [s].[id] = @__orderId_0
> ORDER BY [s].[id], [t].[id]
>
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Core.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'ProductId'.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime order_date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class OrderItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2")]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public int orderId { get; set; } // navigation property
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    [Column("product_id")]
    public int product_id { get; set; } // navigation property
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string? WarehouseSku { get; set; } 
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() { }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : 
    base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
           .ToTable("ShipEngineOrders", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());

        //modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>()
        //    .Property(i => i.product_id).HasColumnName("product_id");

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>()
           .ToTable("ShipEngineOrderItems", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .ToTable("Products", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fluent API for reference. Add these 2 references

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


public partial class OrderItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2")]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")] // add foreign key reference here
    public int orderId { get; set; } // navigation property
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    [Column("product_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Product")] //This is the foreign key reference
    public int product_id { get; set; } // navigation property
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order{ get; set; }
}
```

In addition, try to practise convention over configuration. If your database design is using ProductId instead of product_id. The foreign key configuration is setup automatically.This applies the same to OrderId instead of orderId

Comment: That's not fluent API.

Comment: [ForeignKey("Order")] < this is not fluet api? https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx#:~:text=Entity%20Framework%20Fluent%20API%20is,acts%20as%20a%20Fluent%20API.

Comment: No, definitely not. It's data annotations. The link also tells this. See "Fluent API Methods".

Comment: Thank you, Yat Fei.  It works by adding [ForeignKey("Product")] in OrderItem.cs.  Unfortunately, I can't change the table column, it's being used by other app and I don't have permission to change.  Property orderId in OrderItem table is fine.  It resolved by EF automatically.